# How to read parquet file directly without registering TempTable in SparkSQL

Tags: apache-spark-sql

When I run SQLs over parquet files, I always called `sqlContext.read.parquet()` => `df.registerTempTable()` => `sqlContext.sql()` like this:

```
val df = sqlContext.read.parquet("path/to/2016.05.30/")
df.registerTempTable("tab")
sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM tab")
```

[the Spark Manual](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#run-sql-on-files-directly), says that:

```
Instead of using read API to load a file into DataFrame and query it, you can also query that file directly with SQL.

val df = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM parquet.`examples/src/main/resources/users.parquet`")
```

So I've changed like this:

```
val df = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM parquet.`path/to/2016.05.30/`")
```

But I'm getting an error

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: no such table parquet.path/to/2016.05.30/;
```

How Can I query directly?

Comment: Error states table/file is not available at the specified location. What is your Spark Version?

Answer (score 0):

Directly query on files will support from Spark 1.6 onwards. Please check the spark version which you are running.